# Get the component name of links when clicked

Tags: javascript, angular, web-applications, hyperlink, components

In the web application I'm building, when any link is clicked and route is changed, I need to know which component the clicked link belongs to.

like if any link in the header component was clicked 'about us' for example
I need to console log 'header-component' for example,
but if I clicked 'about us' from the footer component, I will get 'footer-component' and so...

This functionality should be added for all the `<a>` elements that can change the route.

Comment: Please try to share a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of what you have tried so far for others to help.

Comment: Theoretically, if you want to avoid updating the `<a>` tags at all costs, you could add a `HostListener` to the header and footer that tracks when a click occurs in either of them. You could use this combined with an observable to figure out how the user navigated. I would highly recommend not doing this though..

Answer (score 0):

You can create an attribute `directive`. for example called `linkTracker` and add it to your `a` tags like below. then in the directive attach to the click, read the value and log it

```
<a linkTracker="about us">

<a linkTracker="footer">
```

link-tracker.directive.ts

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[linkTracker]',
    exportAs: 'linkTracker'
})
export class LinkTrackerDirective
{
    @Input() linkTracker: string;

    @HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
    onClick()
    {
       console.log(this.linkTracker);
    }
 }
```

You can find guide how to create a directive [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angular-directives/)

Comment: but in this case I will need to add this directive to all the '<a>' tags in the application, and there are too many.

Comment: @scriptify.js yes

Comment: man, I know this is a working solution, but the app is huge, and other developers are adding html and new components to it, there should be a better solution than visiting all the <a> tags in the entire app to add these attributes to them.

Comment: @scriptify.js there are some ways you can intercept which route (not component) you are coming from, however for that also you need to add some code in all your components

Comment: @scriptify.js see this https://blog.hackages.io/our-solution-to-get-a-previous-route-with-angular-5-601c16621cf0

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem with a directive:

```
    import { Directive, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

    @Directive({
       selector: '[myParent]'
    })
    export class MyParentDirective {
        @Input('myParent') parent: string;
        @HostListener('click') onMouseClick() {
            this.showParent();
        }
        constructor() { }

        showParent(){
            console.log(this.parent)
        }
    }
```

and then you can use it like this

```
<a myParent="footer">About Us</a>
```

Comment: but in this case I will need to add this directive to all the '<a>' tags in the application, and there are too many.

Comment: You could use find and replace in your ide

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest another solution, if you already know the parent components.
You could use the parents injection for each parent you want to intercept inside the directive.
So the "link directive" will be like this (you have to implement what you need):

```
import { Directive, HostListener, Input, Host, Inject, forwardRef,Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';

  @Directive({
      selector: 'a'
  })
  export class LinkDirective {
      @HostListener('click') onMouseClick() {
          this.showParent();
      }

      parent: FooterComponent | NavbarComponent;

      constructor(@Optional() @Inject(forwardRef(() => FooterComponent)) private footer?: FooterComponent,
      @Optional() @Inject(forwardRef(() => NavbarComponent)) navbar?: NavbarComponent) { 
        console.log(footer, navbar)
        if(footer){
          this.parent = footer;
        }
        if(navbar){
          this.parent = navbar
        }
        if(!this.parent){
          this.parent = null;
        }
      }

      showParent(){
          console.log(this.parent, (this.parent) ? this.getTagName(this.parent.constructor.name) : null);
      }

      getTagName(el: string){
        return 'my-' + el.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2').toLowerCase();
      }
  }
```

In this case I want to see if an 'a' tag is inside the `Navbar` or the `Footer`, the other components in the middle will be ignored.
You could have a problem if two components that you want to intercept are one inside the other cause both will be injected inside the directive, so I don't know if this is the best solution to your problem, but in this case you avoid to write in every single link the directive name.

I've done a little [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mevjcx?file=src%2Fapp%2Flink.directive.ts) to show you how it works.

By the way if you're sure that every link is a direct children of a component injected in your directive you could add the `@Host()` decorator before `@Optional()` you'll obtain this behaviour and you'll solve the problem of having more than one injection for each link:

**NavbarComponent injected:**

```
<my-navbar>
    <a>Test</a>
</my-navbar>
```

**NavbarComponent not injected:**

```
<my-navbar>
    <my-middle-component>
        <a>Test</a>
    </my-middle-component>
</my-navbar>
```